# How to search for specific word in xml file in windows command

Tags: c#, cmd

I have following content in my file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
    <?define MajorVersion = "2" ?>
    <?define MinorVersion = "5" ?>
    <?define BuildNumber = "64" ?>
    <?define RevisionNumber = "0" ?>
    <?define FullVersion = "$(var.MajorVersion).$(var.MinorVersion).$(var.BuildNumber).$(var.RevisionNumber)"?>
</Include>
```

I want to read this file during PostBuild or AfterBuild event in c#. As access to windows commands are available during this event, I am trying to use cmd to read variables value defined in it i.e. value of **"MajorVersion", "MinorVersion", "BuildNumber" and "RevisionNumber"**. Then I will run the command to rename a folder using these variables. How could I read those specific values in cmd prompt/batch?

For the file content I posted above, I want folder to be renamed to "2.5.64.0".

I looked into this solution - [Read XML file with windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849211/read-xml-file-with-windows-batch)
In the above link, value is present between two nodes but in my case values are present as attribute's value.

Comment: Your easiest bet would be to write a .bat file that parses that file and creates the folder. then just execute that file as your post build step. If you are building in VSTS online, there are plugins to do that sort of stuff. But if it is on your local machine, you will probably have to handle it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read XML file with windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849211/read-xml-file-with-windows-batch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following commands in batch file to achieve the required output:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "MajorVersion="
set "MinorVersion="
set "BuildNumber="
set "RevisionNumber="

for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /c:"MajorVersion =" xmlFile.xml') do set "MajorVersion=%%a"
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /c:"MinorVersion =" xmlFile.xml') do set "MinorVersion=%%a"
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /c:"BuildNumber =" xmlFile.xml') do set "BuildNumber=%%a"
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /c:"RevisionNumber =" xmlFile.xml') do set "RevisionNumber=%%a"

echo %MajorVersion%
echo %MinorVersion%
echo %BuildNumber%
echo %RevisionNumber%"

set "FullVersion=%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%BuildNumber%.%RevisionNumber%"
echo %FullVersion%

rename "OldFolderName" %FullVersion%
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, you can't read a file into a variable in a VS post-build event. 
However, you can run an external batch file and provide it with arguments. You can trigger this batch file and have batch file read xml file and create required folder:

```
CD "$(ProjectDir)"
IF EXIST postBuild.bat (
@ECHO Post-build script exists at: $(ProjectDir)postBuild.bat - executing...
CALL "$(ProjectDir)postBuild.bat" "$(XmlFilePath)" 
)
```

The batch file postBuild.bat in the project dir then looks something like this:

```
@REM **********
@REM Post-build script; assumes params:
@REM postBuild.bat "$( XmlFilePath)"
@REM **********

@ECHO XmlFilePath: %1
[...]
```

Comment: the question was that I want to read specific values from the xml file in the batch file i.e in cmd prompt basically. I wasn't asking about the approach